# Unreal Engine / IOS - Associated Domains / Universal links

Tags: ios, deep-linking, unreal-engine4, associated-domains

Was wondering how to set up IOS Universal Links / Associated Domains in Unreal Engine.

Basically we have two apps, one an older app built in IOS native/Xcode and a new side app showing off some new features/marketing that was built in Unreal Engine 4.18 (BluePrints only).  The goal is to have them be able to deep link to eachother and make use of Universal Links overall for marketing/usage purposes.  This isn't a problem with the older IOS native app as XCode can handle this but there seems to be no documentation on how to make sure the entitlements are setup correctly in Unreal Engine for this.

I'm probably missing something very simple (like the naming structure of the Bundle Identifier) but curious on what to do in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can add an entitlements file to the "[YourProject]\Build\IOS" folder. The file must be named "[GameName].entitlements". The iOS packaging tool will use this file when generating the IPA.